# Find the function p(x)

Tags: functions, polynomials

Solve for $p(x)$:

$$(x-1)\cdot p(x)=x^3+x-2$$

I made this expression:

$$p(x)=\frac{x^3+x-2}{x-1}$$

But no matter what I tried I couldn't simplify this further. I sat with this problem for over 2 hours and could not find a solution. I looked online for an explanation but could not find it. Can you please explain  in detail how and why I can simplify this further. I found the solution but it didn't explain why that was the solution. Please note that this is not my math homework, I just want to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: $p(x)=x^{2}+x+2$.

Comment: Do you try divide the polynomial?

Comment: Hint : Factorize denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $p(x+1) = \frac{(x+1)^3+(x+1)-2}{x} = x^2+3x+4$

So $p(x) = (x-1)^2 +3(x-1)+4 = x^2+x+2$

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can simply use a polynomial division algorithm. Alternatively, by the phrasing of the question, it is obvious it is likely able to be simplified:

$(x^{3}+x-2)=(x-1)(x^{2}+...)$ start this way to handle the $x^{3}$.

Now we want to cancel out the $x^{2}$ term since the $LHS$ does not have one. The only way is to add $x$ which gives us $-x^{2}$ and a $-x$ to take care of. The constant that will add back $2x$ and coincidentally a $-2$ in the final expression to give $+x$ and $-2$ in the final expression.

In questions like this, one can repeat a similar process as the question likely implies a proper divisor.

Comment: Not sure what I missed, nor about your comment. Suspended for now anyway

Comment: @Quanto You didn't miss anything! However, your answer basically assumed the OP could factor $x^{3}-1$ easily. But if s/he could, they also could factor the original expression they have above. In short, I believe others thought it was unhelpful for someone asking the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* When you see problems like this (that is, division problems with a polynomial of higher degree in the numerator and a linear polynomial in the denominator), let the denominator be equal to a new variable. In this case let $x-1=u$ and see what you obtain.

Comment: While this didn't directly answer the question, I think it's a very good technique. I was able to solve the problem myself by doing this. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

if x-1=0 then x=1 thus $x^3$+x-2=1+1-2=0 thus (x-1)|($x^3$+x-2)

Now since we know it's divisible by (x-1) we do the division:

$x^3$+x-2 - $x^2$ (x-1) = -$x^2$+x-2

-x^2+x-2 + x (x-1) = 2x-2

2x-2 - 2 (x-1) = 0

thus $\frac{x^3+x-2}{x-1} = x^2-x+2$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $p(x)$ is of the form $p(x)=x^2+ax+b$

So we have just two coefficients to find (the one of $x^2$ being trivially $1$) and we can do it by simply plugging values for $x$.

- $x=0$ you get $(0-1)p(0)=0^2+0-2\iff (-1)b=-2\iff b=2$
- $x=1$ gives nothing
- $x=2$ gives $p(2)=8\iff 6+2a=8\iff a=1$